# Info.plist not in "Info" - Tab anymore

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

In Xcode my info.plist file is suddenly not in the "Info" Tab in my Target Settings anymore,
I can see and edit it from my Supporting Files Folder, but it disappeared from the Info Tab, like i said, there is just the possibility to add "Document Types", "Exported/Imported UTIs" and "URL Types".
How can i get my Info.plist to appear here again?

(newest Xcode is Installed, iOS 6 SDk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that in Xcode 5 DP the Info Tab is "filled" with the Info.plist again, so this might have been an Issue with Xcode 4.